# Convolution of Generating Functions

Tags: generating-functions

If I have given the following generating function

$$B = \sum_{n > 0}  x^n \sum_{k_1  + \cdots + k_c = n} a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c)$$

is it possible to obtain a nice convolution expression for $a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c)$ in terms of some generating function A?

What bothers me is the summation-constraint $k_1  + \cdots + k_c = n$ of the inner sum, thus it is not straight forward for me to come up with a convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes:
$$
 \begin{eqnarray}
B(x) &=& \sum_{n > 0}  x^n \sum_{k_1  + \cdots + k_c = n} a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c) = \sum_{n > 0}  x^n \sum_{k_1,\ldots, k_c >0 } \delta_{n, k_1+\cdots+k_c} a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c) \\
 &=&  \sum_{k_1,\ldots, k_c >0 } \left( \sum_{n > 0}  x^n \delta_{n, k_1+\cdots+k_c} \right) a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c) \\
  &=& \sum_{k_1,\ldots, k_c >0 } x^{k_1 + \cdots+k_c} a(k_1)  \cdots  a(k_c) = 
     \left( \sum_{k_1 >0 } x^{k_1} a(k_1)\right) \cdots  \left( \sum_{k_c >0 } x^{k_c} a(k_c)\right) = (A(x))^c
\end{eqnarray}
$$